# Why are several Biblical characters called "man of the Lord" (Ish HaElokim), but no one in the Bible is ever "man of God" (Ish Hashem)?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, hebrew, theology, tanach

Ramban makes this observation (Deut. 33:1), and says "anyone with a good intellect" can figure out the reason.  Okay I'm stumped ... help me out here please?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's related to the idea that the Name Havayah refers to Hashem as He transcends all of creation, while Elokim represents His immanence within it. Describing someone as *ish ha-* implies a closeness with the linked object (as in this coming week's parshah, where Noach is described as *ish ha-adamah*, "a man of the ground," i.e., someone devoted to farming - or as in the common use of "ish" to mean "husband"). But since "no man may see Me and live" (Ex. 33:20), then it's impossible to describe any human being as "ish Havayah."

Answer (score 2):

The Shem Hashem is Chesed and the Shem Elokim is Din. When someone is called Ish HaElokim it means that Al Pi Din he deserves it.